# HTML Table left justified

Tags: html

The table is formatted fine when the page is first loaded but when the hide is clicked it calls the JavaScript function that hides and after the show is clicked it runs the JavaScript function to show the table gets left justified in Chrome. Works fine in IE11.  All JavaScript code is to just change the display.

```html
<script language=javascript src='JavaScripts/hbs-ts2.js?v310151'></script>

<body onload='if(typeof(ResetToolbar)=="function") ResetToolbar(); InitPageTimer(1800);' OnClick='ResetPageTimer();' OnKeyPress='ResetPageTimer();' onUnLoad='StopPageTimer(); if(typeof(ResetToolbar)=="function") ResetToolbar();'>
  <BR>
  <A Name=Top></A>
  <center>
    <span align='center' id=spanStatisticsShow style='display: none'>
          <a href='javascript:ToggleDisplay("spanStatisticsShow");ToggleDisplay("spanStatistics");'>Show Timesheet Statistics
          </a>
          </span>
    <span align='center' id=spanStatistics style='display: table'>
             <TABLE CLASS=cTable BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=4 CELLSPACING=0>
             <tr>
                <TH class='TH1'></TH>
                <TH class='TH1' ALIGN=MIDDLE>
                   <b>Timesheet Status Information (Total Timesheets=7)
                   </b>
                </TH>
                <TH class='TH1' ALIGN=RIGHT>
                   <a href='javascript:ToggleDisplay("spanStatistics");javascript:ToggleDisplay("spanStatisticsShow")'>Hide
                   </a>
                </TH>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td valign='middle'>
                   <img src='http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:0.00,100.00&chs=300x115&chl=0.00%|100.00%&chco=00FF00,FF0000&chf=bg,s,EFEFEF&chtt=Completion&chts=333366,12&chdl=Completed|Not Completed&chco=00FF00,FF0000&chdlp=b' 
                      />
                </td>
                <td>
                   <table CLASS=cTable BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=4 CELLSPACING=0 >
                      <tr>
                         <td colspan='6' align='center'>
                            <b>
                            <a href='deptrvw.asp?UID=00f4003a006b004c007c00a1002a002a005f005f004e0006201e&deptno=40218198&Payperiod=08%2F22%2F2021+%2D+09%2F04%2F2021'>Show All 7
                            </a>
                            </b>
                         </td>
                      </tr>
                      <TR>
                      <TR>
                         <td>
                            <a href='deptrvw.asp?UID=00f4003a006b004c007c00a1002a002a005f005f004e0006201e&deptno=40218198&Payperiod=08%2F22%2F2021+%2D+09%2F04%2F2021&FilterID=1'>Approved
                            </a>
                         </td>
                         <td>2</td>
                         <td>
                            <a href='deptrvw.asp?UID=00f4003a006b004c007c00a1002a002a005f005f004e0006201e&deptno=40218198&Payperiod=08%2F22%2F2021+%2D+09%2F04%2F2021&FilterID=2'>Not Approved
                            </a>
                         </td>
                         <td>5</td>
                         <td>Completed</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                      </TR>
                   </table>
       </center>
       </span>
```

Comment: Run your markup through the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) Much of your markup is obsolete. Also, the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. And JavaScript is one word, not two.

Comment: Really should not be calling JavaScript from anchor elements in 2022.